# How to pass mysql query in function and get the results

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Hello I have database and queries written in a module and I am calling the module from the main class. What I want is to pass a query in function and get results. This is what I am doing so far

**database.js**

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'xxxx',
    password : 'xxx',
    database : 'xxx'


});

exports.executeQuery=function(query,callback){
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
            console.log("error comes " + err);
            callback(true);
            return;
        }
        connection.query(query,function(err,results){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                console.log("no error");

                callback(false,{rows: results});
            }
            // check null for results here
        });
        connection.on('error', function(err) {
            callback(true);
            return;
        });
    });
};
```

and in my main class

```
 var db = require('./database');
 var user_id = 5
 var query = "SELECT * FROM contacts  WHERE user_id = ?", user_id;
 db.executeQuery(query, function(r,contact_details) {
    console.log("success");          
    console.log(contact_details);
 });
```

It doesn't work. It doesn't even go inside the function or prints `success` string. But If I do query this

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
```

This will work. But I want to send a conditional query and because of conditional query, it doesn't work. Don't know how to send a conditional query, for example, this query

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM contacts  WHERE user_id = ?", user_id;
```

or

```
"SELECT count(*) as count FROM user_info  WHERE user_id = ? AND phone_no_1 = ? OR  phone_no_2 = ? OR  phone_no_3 = ?",[user_id,formatted_sms_no,formatted_sms_no,formatted_sms_no],
```

These kind of queries. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use prepared statement instead, then bind the parameters into an external variable where you can assign an array of values

Comment: how can I do that? Could you please edit my code?

Comment: As far as I see in module [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries) you have the feature called preparing queries. So basically you should pass `query` and `parameters` for executing, f.e. your function definition will look like this `function(query, parameters, callback)`, and than use `mysql.format(query, parameters)` before executing the query.

Comment: @Logans It works. Thank you. Please post as an answer so I mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see in module [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#preparing-queries) you have the feature called preparing queries.

So basically you should pass `query` and `parameters` for executing, f.e. your function definition will look like this `function(query, parameters, callback)`, and than use `mysql.format(query, parameters)` before executing the query.